# The generating function for the Fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

Prove that $$1+z+2z^2+3z^3+5z^4+8z^5+13z^6+...=\frac{1}{1-(z+z^2)}$$

The coefficients are Fibonacci numbers, i.e., the sequence $\left\{1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,...\right\}$.

Comment: Mosquito nuking version: use Binet's formula, sum the resulting geometric series...

Comment: I like @GlenO’s answer very well, but when I explain this to a class, I just divide $1-z-z^2$ into $1$ using ordinary long division (writing terms in ascending order, of course). Then I point out that at each step, the coefficients add in just the right way. This makes things clear, there’s no mystery at all.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: **Hint:** $a=\dfrac bc\iff b=ac.$

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The proof is quite simple. Let's write our sum in a compact format:

$$
1+z+2z^2+3z^3+5z^4+8z^5+... = \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_nz^n
$$
Where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number, starting with $F_0=F_1=1$, and $F_{n+2}=F_n+F_{n+1}$. It is from here that we will prove what needs to be proven.

$$\begin{align}
(1-z-z^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_nz^n &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_nz^n - \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_nz^{n+1} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_nz^{n+2}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_nz^n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty F_{n-1}z^n-\sum_{n=2}^\infty F_{n-2}z^n\\
&= F_0 + (F_1-F_0)z + \sum_{n=2}^\infty (F_n-F_{n-1}-F_{n-2})z^n
\end{align}$$
Now, $F_1=F_0$ and $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$. Therefore,

$$
(1-z-z^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_nz^n = F_0 = 1
$$
And thus

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_nz^n = \frac{1}{1-(z+z^2)}
$$

Comment: One short comment which I encountered, the "modern fibonacci number" had an extra term 0 thus $Fnew_{1}=Ftradition_{0}=1$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number    ) where the series expansion textbook did was based on $Ftradition_{0}=1$.

Comment: This one might help people like me - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZlEbRJNO68

Comment: you have started knowing the gf. which made it simpler for you ton know what to multiply it with. What if it was a find question instead of proof?

Comment: @sibillalazzerini - You can work the mathematical expressions in reverse, beginning with $\sum (F_n-F_{n-1}-F_{n-2})z^n$, and getting to $(1-z-z^2)\sum F_nz^n - F_0 - (F_1-F_0)z$, and finish from there.

Answer (score 39):

$\dfrac{1}{1-(z+z^2)}=1+(z+z^2)+(z+z^2)^2....$ The  coefficient of $z^n$ is therefore the number of ways of adding 1s and 2s to get $n$.  Also, the number of ways to do this is given by the Fibonacci numbers, proving the result.

Answer (score 14):

A related [technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499073/discrete-math-exponential-generating-series/499110#499110). What you have is the ordinary generating function of Fibonacci numbers. Use the recurrence relation of the Fibonacci numbers

$$ F_{n+2} = F_{n+1} + F_{n} $$

to get the generating function. See here for a [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337842/simplifying-catalan-number-recurrence-relation/337885#337885).

**Added:** We will derive the ordinary generating function. Let $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} F_n z^n $, $F_0=F_1=1$, then

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} F_{n+2} z^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} F_{n+1} z^n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} F_{n} z^n   $$

$$\implies \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} F_{n} z^{n-2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F_{n} z^{n-1} + g(z) $$

$$\implies  \frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} F_{n} z^{n} =\frac{1}{z} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F_{n} z^{n} + g(z) $$

$$ \implies \frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} F_{n} z^{n}-\frac{F_0}{z^2}-\frac{F_1}{z}= \frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} F_{n} z^{n}-\frac{F_0}{z} + g(z) $$

$$ \implies \frac{g(z)}{z^2}-\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{z}g(z)-\frac{1}{z} + g(z) $$

$$ \implies g(z) = \frac{1}{1-(z+z^2)}. $$

Comment: Your very first displayed equality is incorrect; it's not true that $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} F_{n+2}z^n$.

Comment: @Downvoter: As you see it is the first answer to be posted and it is correct!! Can you explain yourself?

Comment: As @ShtreevatsaR pointed out, $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{n+2} z^n$ is false. I don't think this warrants a down vote though.

Comment: @Braindead: Off course it is correct.

Comment: @Braindead: Please take yourtime to understand what's going on. The answer is correct.

Comment: Since you refused to acknowledge the existence the trivial mistake on your solution, I fixed it for you. In the future, I suggest that you drop your condescending attitude and carefully examine your own solution.

Comment: @Braindead: Thanks for doing that. I was checking but I did not spot it. It is a typo. Thank you again. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Braindead: Do not rush to judge people's attitude if you do not them well.

Answer (score 12):

Since Fibbonacci series starts at $0$ this series is sometimes called **shifted Fibonacci sequence**
$F_0=1,F_1=1,F_2=2,F_3=3,F_4=5,...$
$$ F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2},n\ge 2$$
Denote by $$F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_nx^n=1+x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}F_nx^n=1+x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(F_{n-1}+F_{n-2})x^n=$$ 
$$=1+x+x\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}F_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}F_{n-2}x^{n-2}=$$ 
$$=1+x+x(-1+F_0x^0+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}F_{n-1}x^{n-1})+x^2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}F_{n-2}x^{n-2}=$$ 
$$=1+x+x(-1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{n-1}x^{n-1})+x^2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}F_{n-2}x^{n-2}=$$
$$=1+x+x(-1+F(x))+x^2F(x)=1+xF(x)+x^2F(x)$$ 
or
$$F(x)=1+xF(x)+x^2F(x)$$
solving this equation we get
 $$F(x)=\frac{1}{1-x-x^2}$$

Comment: Hi @Adi Dani  how can one find the coefficient of Fibonacci series (of step-d): $\frac{1}{1-x-x^2-...-x^{d-1}}$ ?