# Solve recurrence relation $ a_{n+1} = (n+1)a_n + 1 $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$a_0 = 1 \\ a_{n+1} = (n+1)a_n + 1 $

Could you help me solve this?
And maybe someone know good source explaining how to solve recurrence relations?

Comment: Hint: Try to find and solve the recursion for $b_n=a_n/n!$.

Comment: **Hint:** you can use [generating function technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372439/finding-generating-function-for-the-recurrence-a-0-1-a-n-n-choose-2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @Did said in the comments  we can put

$$ n!b_n = a_n \Rightarrow (n+1)!b_{n+1} = (n+1)!b_n + 1 $$

$$ \Rightarrow (b_{n+1} - b_n)(n+1)! = 1 \Rightarrow b_{n+1} - b_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} $$

you can do the following because you'll get a telescoping sum  $$ \sum_{n=0}^k (b_{n+1} - b_n)  = \sum_{n=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{n!} \Rightarrow b_{k+1} - b_0 = \sum_{n=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{n!} $$

$$ a_0 = 1 = 0!b_0 = b_0 \Rightarrow b_{k+1} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{n!} \Rightarrow b_n = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}  $$

$$ \Rightarrow a_n= n! \left(1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}  \right) $$

Answer (score 2):

It's always a good idea to compute the first few terms of a sequence and check them with the OEIS.  In this case you get [A000522](http://oeis.org/A000522).