# How to find the general term of this recursive sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$ (a_n)_{a \ge 1}, a_{n+1} = (n+1)a_n + 1, a_1 = 1  $$

I found the first 5 terms and I got 1, 3, 10, 41, 206, but I don't know what to do next? I tries OEIS but it just shows me the recursive formula again. I know that the answer is $ a_n = n!(1 + 1/2! + ... + 1/n!) $ but how do I get to that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve recurrence relation $ a_{n+1} = (n+1)a_n + 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532020) - initial condition there $a_0=1$ instead of $a_1=1$, but that is just a detail

Comment: You can prove this by induction.