# Calculate $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{H_n}{10^n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Question is like in the title and my attempt is

Let have sequence $$a_n = <\frac{H_0}{10^0},\frac{H_1}{10^1},\frac{H_2}{10^2},\dots>$$ 
where $H_n$ is n-th harmonic number.

And we have to construct $$b_n = \langle a_0,a_0+a_1,a_0+a_1+a_2,\dots\rangle$$
and it will be our answer.

Let's have generating function for sequence $a_n$: $$A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$

And generating function for sequence $b_n$ will be $$B(x) = \frac{A(x)}{1-x}$$

I started making $\frac{H_n}{10^n}$ a bit easier(there are my doubts).

we can rewrite $H_n$ as $$1+\dfrac12+\dfrac13+\dots = 1+\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\dfrac22}{n!} = 1+\frac{n(n+1)-2}{2*n!}$$
so now we can rewrite $a_n$ as $$a_n =\langle\frac{1}{10^n}+\frac{n(n+1)-2}{2*n!*10^n}\rangle$$

Generating function for $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{10^n}x^n = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{10}x}$$

But i'm having problem with second part of it... 
And i'm not sure if i don't overcomplicated this task by making it "easier". I'd like to use generating functions cause it's task for them, but i'd be happy to see some other solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please consider \langle and \rangle to give $\langle$ and $\rangle$ instead of $<$ and $>$. Moreover, please consider \left\langle \right\rangle in pairs to give large pairs:
$$\left\langle \frac{a}{b}\right\rangle$$

Comment: The summation of the $H_n$ you did is not correct.

Comment: You have a sequence that is easy to differentiate $\Delta H_n=1/(n+1)$ and a sequence (geometric) that is easy to integrate $\sum_{n=1}^{m}1/10^n=\frac{10^{-m-1}-1}{10^{-1}-1}$. So, [summation by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the well known identity

> $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } H_{n}{z}^{n}= \frac{\ln(1-z)}{z-1}. $$

Comment: Oh wow... haven't thought about it this way! Amazing way of thinking, thanks!

Comment: @Chris: You are very welcome.

Comment: I want to be sure, so sorry about novice question. 
If we want to calculate anything from $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$
we need to be sure that this sum converges right?
i mean $$\sum x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$, but to plug in some $x$ we have to know that this sum converges for given $x$?

Comment: And in general, from a generating function $f$ of a sequence, to get the generating function of the partial sums, you can try $f(x)/(1-x)$.

Comment: @Chris: Generally, getting a closed form for the ordinary generating function depends on $a_n$. see for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372439/finding-generating-function-for-the-recurrence-a-0-1-a-n-n-choose-2).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal, yes i know that, but let's say we have to calculate $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac12$$
I think we can plug in $x=\dfrac12$ into $$\sum x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$, because $\frac{1}{2^n}\rightarrow 0$? Or my logic is wrong?

Comment: @Chris: Are you trying to derive some conditions on $a_n$ so you can ensure the convergence?

Comment: @moderators: As I said before "the option of downvoting has been abused by some users". It is the second downvote on this post!!

Answer (score 2):

It is known that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} H_n x^n = -\frac{\log{(1-x)}}{1-x}$$

Plug in $x=1/10$.

I don't think $H_0$ is defined.

**EDIT**

You can define $H_0=0$ using the expression

$$H_n = \int_0^1 dx \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$$

Comment: I think it is reasonable to define $H_0=0$. Either way, it does not change the answer.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but i marked first one:)

Comment: @Chris: you're welcome.  I posted it without seeing his, I guess we were within seconds.

Comment: If you define $H_n = \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \frac{1}{k}$, then (the empty sum) $H_0 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

It's straightforward to prove the identity by formal manipulation actually. You want $\displaystyle\sum_{n \ge 0} H_n \frac{1}{10^n}$, so let's consider the generating function $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} H_n z^n$, and evaluating $A(\frac1{10})$ will give the answer you want.

By definition, we have
$$A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} H_n z^n = \sum_{n \ge 0} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} z^n = \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac1k \sum_{n \ge k} z^n = \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac1k \frac{z^k}{1-z} = \frac{1}{1-z} \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{z^k}{k} = \frac{1}{1-z} \ln \frac{1}{1-z}.$$

The last step, the well-known series for $\displaystyle \ln \frac{1}{1-z}$, can itself be derived as follows (interpret $\int (\cdot)$ as $\int_0^z (\cdot)\, dz$):

$$\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{z^k}{k} = \sum_{k \ge 0} \int z^k = \int \sum_{k \ge 0} z^k = \int \frac{1}{1-z} = -\ln(1-z).$$