# Using generation functions solve the following difference equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, recurrence-relations

Using generation functions solve the following difference equation

$$  a_{n+1} - 3a_{n+2} + 2a_n = 7n ; n\geq0; a_0 = -1; a_1 = 3. $$

Comment: What have you done so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: The [same question was posted an hour ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754425/solving-difference-equations-using-generation-functions) by the same user, who's since deleted it for unclear reasons.

Comment: Why did you delete the previous post ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It was a mistake I deleted it and didn't know how to get it back. I'm new to this

Comment: A [related tecbnique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372439/finding-generating-function-for-the-recurrence-a-0-1-a-n-n-choose-2).

Comment: "It was a mistake" Hmmm... and you also chose to disregard the advice given to you there that "You can post your initial steps, and also what final answer you got" (advice repeated here by another user, and similarly disregarded).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the hint was able to solve it. This was my solution.

$$  a_{n+1} - 3a_{n+2} + 2a_n = 7n ; n\geq0; a_0 = -1; a_1 = 3. $$

$$  (\frac{a{(z)} - a_{0} + za_1}{z^2}) - 3(\frac{a{(z)} - a_{0}}{z^2}) + 2a(z) = \frac{7z}{(1 - z)^2}; a_0 = -1; a_1 = 3. $$

Substitute values in:

$$  (\frac{a{(z)} + 1 - 3z}{z^2}) - 3(\frac{a{(z)} + 1}{z^2}) + 2a(z) = \frac{7z}{(1 - z)^2}; a_0 = -1; a_1 = 3. $$

Expand and multiply through by $z^2$

$$  a(z) + 1 -3z - 3a(z)z -3z + 2a(z)z^2 = \frac{7z^3}{(1 - z)^2} $$

$$  a(z)[1 -3z + 2z^2] = \frac{7z^3}{(1 - z)^2} + 6z - 1 $$

$$  a(z) = \frac{13z^3 - 13z^2 + 8z -1}{(z-1)^2(2z-1)}$$

By Partial Fraction decomposition:

$$  a(z) = \frac{-11}{(2z-1)} + \frac{12}{(z-1)} + \frac{7}{(z-1)^2} + \frac{7}{(z-1)^3}$$

By Extracting coefficients we get: 
$$  a(z) = \frac{-7[n(n+1)]}{2} + 11 * 2^n - 12$$

Comment: That's how it is done. Did you check the solution?I believe you left out the term with the square.

Answer (score 1):

Define the generating function $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, multiply your recurrence by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$, Recognize, e.g.:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 2} z^n &= \frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} z^n &= \frac{1}{1 - z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} n z^n &= z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \frac{1}{1 - z}
\end{align}
Solve the result for $A(z)$, write as partial fractions (a computer algebra system helps), and read off the coefficients by using geometric series or:
$$
(1 + u)^{-m}
    = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-m}{k} u^k
    = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{k + m - 1}{m - 1} (-1)^k u^k
$$

Comment: Typo: $(1+u)^\color{red}{m}$

Comment: @Anant, thank you. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint was able to solve it. This was my solution. @vonbrand