# Going from recurrence relations to closed form

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form

How do I go from the following recurrence relation

```
a(n) = (n+1)a(n-1) where a(0) = 2
```

to a closed form? I know I need to use an iterative approach but I am not quite sure what to look for.

Comment: Another approach is [generating function approach](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372439/finding-generating-function-for-the-recurrence-a-0-1-a-n-n-choose-2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can divide through by the summation factor $(n+1)!$ to get $${a_n\over (n+1)!}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{n!}$$ Now let $$S_n:=\frac{a_n}{(n+1)!}$$ Thus $S_n=S_{n-1}=c$ is constant, but $a_0=2$ and so $S_0=2/1=2\implies S_n\equiv2$ Thus we have $$a_n=(n+1)!S_n=2\cdot (n+1)!$$

Comment: Thank you, and if I wanted to prove that this answer was correct, would I do that with a proof by induction or what?

Comment: This is sufficient proof in my opinion. You could certainly _verify_ it that way, but there's nothing wrong with a direct derivation.

Comment: What is the approach called that you took to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure - I learned it originally from the book "Concrete Mathematics" by Knuth, et al. See this: http://homepages.gac.edu/~holte/courses/mcs256/documents/first-order-linear-recurrence.pdf They show how to find $S_n$ in general. This method can be used to solve any recurrence of the form $a_nx_n=b_nx_{n-1}+c_n$ so it's fairly powerful and nice to know.