# Find Ordinary Generating Function for $k^3 (k \geq 2)$

Tags: generating-functions

Could we find the OGF for the sequence $k^3, k \geq 2$?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes, tried to differentiate some elementary generating functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372439/finding-generating-function-for-the-recurrence-a-0-1-a-n-n-choose-2)

Apply the operator $(xD)^3= (xD)(xD)(xD) $ to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ gives your the answer.

**Note:**

$$D =\frac{d}{dx}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $~k^3x^k=(x\frac{\partial}{\partial x})^3x^k$