# Explicit formula for a recursive series?

Tags: real-analysis

Finding the explicit formula for a recursive sequence $a$ where
$a_0=3$, $a_1=6$, $a_2=14$, and $a_{n+3}= 6a_{n+2} - 11 a_{n+1}+6a_n $ for $n = 0,1,2\ldots$
$$
S(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n
$$

Prove that the radius of convergence is $R>0$ and $S(x)(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x), x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a square trinomial (find coefficients).

Please a hint, how to do it?

Comment: Step 1 : find the roots of the polynomial $$\lambda^3 - 6\lambda^2 + 11\lambda - 6$$ associated with your recurrence equation. You will find that they are distinct. Let we call them $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$, then any solution of the homogenous recurrence equation will have the form $$a_n = \alpha_1 \lambda_1^n + \alpha_2 \lambda_2^n + \alpha_3 \lambda_3^n.$$ Step 2: Use the initial conditions on $a_0, a_1, a_2$ to fix the unknown coefficients $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,$ and $\alpha_3$.

Comment: hint: $$\lambda^3-6\lambda^2+11\lambda-6=\lambda^3-(3+2+1)\lambda^2+(3\cdot2+3\cdot1+2\cdot1)\lambda-3\cdot2\cdot1$$

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338740/the-generating-function-for-the-fibonacci-numbers/338744#338744) is generating function technique.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal is $S(x)$ not the generating function in question? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have what is known as a *linear homogeneous recurrence relation with constant coefficients*, also saddled with the acromym LHRRWCC. Achille has given you the form of the solution to these critters. Continuing from that comment, once you've found $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ and $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ (hint: all six values are *really* simple), use these to find $S(x)$ by writing
$$\begin{align}
S(x) &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\alpha_1\lambda_1^n+\alpha_2\lambda_2^n+\alpha_3\lambda_3^n)x^n\\
 &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\alpha_1(\lambda_1x)^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\alpha_2(\lambda_2x)^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\alpha_3(\lambda_3x)^n &\text{(Why?)}\\
 &=\frac{\alpha_1}{1-\lambda_1x}+\frac{\alpha_2}{1-\lambda_2x}+\frac{\alpha_3}{1-\lambda_3x} &\text{(Why?)}
\end{align}$$
Knowing what $a_n$ is, the problem expects you to know how to compute the radius of convergence and show that it is greater than zero. This isn't too hard.

Also, knowing what $S(x)$ is, a little algebra should show you that
$$
S(x)(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)
$$
has the form $px^2+qx+r$. As a check for your work, you should discover that
$$
S(x)(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)=11x^2-12x+3
$$
Hope this helps. If not, feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

hint: $$\lambda^3-6\lambda^2+11\lambda-6=\lambda^3-(3+2+1)\lambda^2+(3\cdot2+3\cdot1+2\cdot1)\lambda-3\cdot2\cdot1$$