# Is this number rational or irrational?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Start writing down the Fibonacci numbers, using two digits for each one

```
01 01 02 03 05 08 13 21 34 55 ...
```

Eventually you will reach three digit numbers. When that happens, any digits apart from the last two "overflow", and are carried back through the sequence like this

```
  ... 21 34 55 89
          +     1 44
          +        2 33
     -----------------
= ... 21 34 55 90 46 3? ...
```

This defines a real number, by concatenating the digits of the sequence

$$\phi = 0.01\,01\,02\,03\,05\,08\,13\,21\,34\,55\,90\,46\,3\dots$$

Is $\phi$ rational or irrational?

Comment: Use http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler-Binet_Formula

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty F_n z^n = \frac{z}{1-z-z^2}$, so your sum is $100/9899$, a rational number.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656183/why-does-frac1-99989999-generate-the-fibonacci-sequence

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks. This question was actually inspired by [this topic](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7144616) on Hacker News.

Comment: Generalization: a $k$-places shift.

Answer (score 6):

This is the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{F_n\over100^n},$$
easily summable with the explicit formula for $F_n$.

Comment: In case OP is interested, the sum is $100/9899$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla How long did it take you to come up with this argument? Did you see it instantly?

Comment: Seconds. The hard problem is without the carry digits. Someone overlooked this and answered it in a removed answer!