# A linear non homogeneus recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Im using the minimax algorithm for a very simple game and when counting the tree nodes found the recurrence $T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+1$, with $0$ and $1$ as initial values.

I tried generating functions: $G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T(n)x^n$ and then

\begin{align*}
G(x) &= 0+1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty (T(n-1)+T(n-2)+1)x^n \\
     &= 1+xG(x)+x^2G(x)+x^n \\
     &= \frac{1+\sum x^n}{1-x-x^2}
\end{align*}
and now I dont know whath to do. Any help please?

Comment: What's your goal? Is it to solve the recurrence relation?

Comment: two known series are involved

Comment: Yes, I would like a closed form. The solution to the homogeneus relation is not the problem, of course. But I dont understand how to use it.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209640/solving-a-recurrence-relation-with-the-characteristic-equation).

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338740/the-generating-function-for-the-fibonacci-numbers/338744#338744).

Answer (score 1):

You should have the generating function

> $$ G(x) = {\frac {x}{{x}^{3}-2\,x+1}}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Your generating function isn’t quite right. Since $T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+1-[n=0]$, where $[n=0]$ an [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) and we assume that $T(n)=0$ for all $n\le 0$, we have

$$\begin{align*}
G(x)&=\sum_{n\ge 0}T(n-1)x^n+\sum_{n\ge 0}T(n-2)x^n+\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n-1\\
&=xG(x)+x^2G(x)+\frac1{1-x}-1\\
&=xG(x)+x^2G(x)+\frac{x}{1-x}
\end{align*}$$

and

$$G(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)(1-x-x^2)}\;.$$

Decompose this into partial fractions. If $\varphi=\frac12(1+\sqrt5)$ and $\widehat\varphi=\frac12(1-\sqrt5)$, you’ll find that $1-x-x^2=(1-\varphi x)(1-\widehat\varphi x)$, so your partial fraction decomposition will have the form

$$G(x)=\frac{A}{1-x}+\frac{B}{1-\varphi x}+\frac{C}{1-\widehat\varphi x}\;.\tag{1}$$

Each of the terms on the right-hand side of $(1)$ expands into a power series via

$$\frac1{1-ax}=\sum_{n\ge 0}a^nx^n\;,$$

and you can then combine the summations to get $T(n)$, the coefficient of $x^n$ in $G(x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, apparently, $T(n)=F(n+1)-1$.

Comment: @Miguel: You’re very welcome. Yes, that looks right. In fact, if we’d written out the first few terms ($0,1,2,4,7,12,20$) and guessed that formula, we could simply have proved it by induction.