# Why are the poles of the z-transform of the Fibonacci sequence the golden ratio?

Tags: control-theory, z-transform

I recently derived the poles of the $z$-transform of the Fibonacci sequence to be the golden ratio by doing the following:

$u(k+2)=u(k+1)+u(k); u(0)=u(1)=1$

$z^2U(z)-z^2u(0)-zu(1) = zU(z)-zu(0)+U(z)$

$U(z)(z^2-z-1) = z^2$

$U(z) = \displaystyle\frac{z^2}{z^2-z-1}$

poles: $(z^2-z-1) = 0\rightarrow z = \displaystyle\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$

I could see that they turned out to be the golden ratio when I did this but I'm wondering why that is. What about z-transforms and poles cause this outcome? Why does this result make sense?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/338740).

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? Mathematically or philosophically or whatever?

Comment: Its fairly well known that the Fibonacci sequence and the golden ration are strongly connected, so its not too surprising. See Binet's formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence

Comment: I understand that the Fibonacci sequence is related to the golden ratio, I'm just wondering why the relationship shows up in this way. What is it about z-transforms and their poles specifically that causes this outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Let us start with something a bit more general and consider the sequence
$$
u(n) = \alpha z_1^{n}+\alpha z_2^{n}
$$
where $\alpha=(z_2-1)/(z_2-z_1)$, $\beta=(1-z_1)/(z_2-z_1)$, $z_1>1$, and $z_2<-1$.

From this expression, we obtain
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
L(n)&:=&\dfrac{u(n+1)}{u(n)}\\
&=&\dfrac{\alpha z_1^{n+1}+\alpha z_2^{n+1}}{\alpha z_1^{n}+\alpha z_2^{n}}\\
%
&=&\dfrac{(z_2-1)z_1^{n+1}+(1-z_1)z_2^{n+1}}{(z_2-1)z_1^{n
}+(1-z_1)z_2^{n}}\\
%
&=&\dfrac{z_1[(z_2-1)z_1^{n}+(1-z_1)z_2^{n}]+(1-z_1)z_2^{n+1}-z_1(1-z_2)z_2^n}{(z_2-1)z_1^{n
}+(1-z_1)z_2^{n}}\\
%
&=&z_1+\dfrac{(1-z_1)z_2^{n+1}-z_1(1-z_2)z_2^n}{(z_2-1)z_1^{n
}+(1-z_1)z_2^{n}}\\
%
&=&z_1+\dfrac{z_2^n(z_2-z_1)}{(z_2-1)z_1^{n
}+(1-z_1)z_2^{n}}\\
%
&=&z_1+\dfrac{(z_2-z_1)}{(z_2-1)\left(\dfrac{z_1}{z_2}\right)^n+(1-z_1)}.
%
\end{array}
$$
Since $z_1>z_2$, we have that $(z_1/z_2)^n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, which implies that $L(n)\to z_1$ as $n\to\infty$.

If we pick $z_1=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$, and $z_2=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$, then the sequence is the Fibonacci sequence and we have that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{u(n+1)}{u(n)}=z_1=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.
$$