# Showing $\Bigg[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{2n}\choose{n}}{4^n}x^n\Bigg]^2=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have been trying to show that 
$$\Bigg[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{2n}\choose{n}}{4^n}x^n\Bigg]^2=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n \text{ where }0\leq x<1$$
using only combinatorics.

So far, here is what I have tried:

\begin{align}
\Bigg[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{2n}\choose{n}}{4^n}x^n\Bigg]^2 &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{{{2n}\choose{n}} {{2m}\choose{m}}}{4^{m+n}}x^{m+n}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{k}\frac{{{2(k-m)}\choose{k-m}} {{2m}\choose{m}}}{4^{k}}x^{k}\\
\end{align}

So, it suffices to show the following:
$$\sum_{m=0}^{k}{{2(k-m)}\choose{k-m}} {{2m}\choose{m}}=4^k$$
I can rewrite this like so:
$$\sum_{m=0}^{k}\frac{(2k-2m)!(2m)!}{\big[(k-m)!\big]^2\big(m!\big)^2}=4^k$$

Unfortunately, I don't no how to procede from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It’s easiest to start from the fact that the [central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) have the generating function

$$\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{2n}nx^n\;,$$

so that

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{\binom{2n}n}{4^n}x^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{2n}n\left(\frac{x}4\right)^n=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4\left(\frac{x}4\right)}}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}}\;,$$

and now the result is immediate when you recall that

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n=\frac1{1-x}\;.$$

Comment: Isn't the product in my question the same as the one in your answer? Also, how would you go about showing that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{n\geq0}{{2n}\choose{n}}x^n$$

Comment: @Hrhm: Yes, I was temporarily misled by your intermediate step. You can find a proof of the generating function [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064216/generating-functions-and-central-binomial-coefficient). You can also deduce it from the generating function for the Catalan numbers, which is derived [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/338385/12042).