# In how many ways can n red balls and n blue balls be arranged such that number of red balls from left side is >= number of blue balls?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can 'n' red and 'n' blue balls be arranged, such that at any point from the left hand side, the number of red balls is always greater than or equal to the number of blue balls ?
Example : n = 2
RRBB
RBRB
Answer = 2

Comment: To prevent your question from getting negative attention it is recommended that you study [the guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: Hint: Use the Catalan numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly equal to the $n$-th [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). They're a well studied and interesting group of numbers, and arise from a fundamental recurrence relation which you can actually obtain from your problem as well. This is $$C_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}C_kC_{n-k-1}$$, where $C_0=1$. They also have a closed form binary expression, and you can find a derivation starting from the recurrence [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337842/simplifying-catalan-number-recurrence-relation).

Another useful link is [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/catalan-numbers/). You will notice that the same problem can be reformulated in a number of ways, such as the number of acceptable parantheses sequences (which is exactly your problem, replace red with '(' and blue with ')'), monotonic lattice paths, and what are known as Dyck paths (essentially the same).