# Half-catalan numbers

Tags: recursion, trees, catalan-numbers

I've been interested in counting how many binary trees there are with n leaves. I consider 2 trees to be the same if I can swap the children of nodes to get the other one.

I've started by figuring out the first terms:
1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11

I then quickly found a recursive formula for it:
$$
u_1 = 1 \\
\forall\ n > 1,\ u_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{\text{floor}(n/2)}u_i\times u_{n-i}
$$

It appears this sequence comes with the sweet name of the "Half-Catalan numbers" (found here https://oeis.org/A000992). I can see where this name comes from as this is defined as the Catalan numbers except we do the sum up to $\text{floor}(n/2)$ instead of $n$.

But the Catalan numbers also have a neat non-recursive formula :
$$
u_n = \frac{1}{n+1}{2n \choose n}
$$

So my question is, is there any non-recursive formula for the Half-Catalan numbers as well?

Regards.

Comment: Probably if one were known, it would have been incorporated in the OEIS entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Catalan Numbers there's copious detail of how to derive $C_n=\dfrac1{n+1}\dbinom{2n}n$ starting from the recurrence relation $$C_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}C_kC_{n-1-k}\tag{0}$$ and the initial value $C_0$, *via* the ordinary generating function at the following link.

[Simplifying Catalan number recurrence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337842/simplifying-catalan-number-recurrence-relation/338385#338385)

Perhaps trying to mirror the arguement might result in what you ask for, although it's not for the faint hearted.

The "half catalans" seem to be starting from a less enticing recurrence relation; if that doesn't prove tractable, maybe jump in with the ordinary generating function for the "half catalans", which is given at the link you provided to Sloan's.