# what is result $T(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n T(i-1) T(n-i)$

Tags: summation, recursion

What is result following forlmula?
If suppose $n=5$

$T(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n T(i-1) T(n-i)$

Now every $T$ call again $T(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n T(i-1) T(n-i)$
and we can't get exactly number!

I mean we can't get number from every $T$

So what is the result in the forlmula with $n=5$ ?

Comment: What is the $T(0)$?

Comment: Use generating functions. [This recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Example:_The_generating_function_for_the_Catalan_numbers) is for [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337842/simplifying-catalan-number-recurrence-relation) is another one.

Comment: Thanks to everybody I solved it! if you wanna know how I solved it ... tell me!