# Proof of $C_n = \frac{1}{n + 1} \binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers, formal-power-series

I want to comprehend the first proof of $C_n = \frac{1}{n + 1}\binom{2n}{n}$ on Wikipedia. Link: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof).
I have problems with two steps:

1. $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}y^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n + 1} }{4^n(2n - 1)} \binom{2n}{n}y^n$$ I calculated
   $$\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n} = \frac{(-1)^{n + 1}}{4^n} \frac{(n - 1.5) \cdot (n - 1.5 - 1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (n - 1.5 - (n - 3) + 1) }{n!}$$, but how to proceed?
2. One shall insert $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4^n(2n-1)}\binom{2n}{n} x^n$$ into $$\frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - 4x}}{2x} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{x}(1 - \sqrt{1 - 4x})$$ by using standard power series operations. But how do we handle the division of $1$ by $x$ in terms of $x^n$? The wikipedia entry for power series says that the first coeffizient of the division is calculated as $d_0 = \frac{a_0}{b_0}$, but for $x = \sum b_n x^n$, $b_0$ is 0, such that we get a division by zero.

Please note that we consider formal power series, so I do not know if and how we can somehow detour via an other development point.

Background: The problem occured during computing the moments of the semicircular distribution in free probability theory.

EDIT: While elaborating the solution (I admit that I never had found it by myself) given by @BrianM.Scott, the specific second question was solved too: One does not calculate $\frac{1}{x}$ directly, but splits the sum up and lets the dangerous constant terms (for $n = 0$) eliminate one another before dividing the remaining sum terms (for $n > 0$) by $x$.

Comment: You are right, I've edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: See if [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337842/simplifying-catalan-number-recurrence-relation/338385#338385) helps.

Comment: What does the notation $(n-1,5)$ refer to?

Comment: Your calculation of $\,{\frac12 \choose n}\,$ is wrong.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: I believe that it’s $n-\frac32$, with the decimal comma.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: You are right, It should be interpreted as $n - \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Write your first comment as answer and I will accept it. It helped _a lot_.

Comment: @Somos: I think that I simply chose a wrong way to calculate it.

Comment: @user7427029: I’ve now done so; I’m glad that it was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337842/simplifying-catalan-number-recurrence-relation/338385#338385) I wrote out a more detailed version of the argument in Wikipedia. It covers the evaluation of $\binom{\frac12}n$ in detail and also shows how to deal with the constant term, so it may answer your questions.